# How to procedurally create random scratched and damaged material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shader-nodes

I've been trying to get a procedurally (so, no image textures) generated scratches/damage map, that looks something like the below image.

[image: procedural scratched/damaged materigl]

I've tried to find and combine youtube tutorials, and the previous solutions provided at Blender.SE, but I can't get it to look anything remotely like the intended result :-(

Does anyone know a node setup that gives a result that resembles the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is surely not completely similar to your image.
But this will surely help you get started.

For the scratches part you can use a voronoi texture set to Distance to Edge. Using a less than node you can mask out the borders of the cells. Use another texture to mask out some of these edges (I have used another voronoi texture)

For the rough noisy part you can use a similar technique. Take a noise texture and mask out parts of it using another texture.

Procudural masks like scratches are usually an expirimentation with masking textures using other textures. Try all the available textures and experiment with different blending modes.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -2):

of course there is a way but most likely it will be long and time consuming I personally use substance painter for that stuff it's way faster and efficient for these type of problems I highly recommend it to level UP your work.